# Concern on performance overhead for image scale

Tags: android

My android app will work for both normal and hdpi device. I don't want to create two sets of images assets for normal and hdpi screen.

So, could I just create image assets for hdpi only, and use them for both normal and hdpi device. Of course, the hdpi images will be auto scaled to fit normal screen devices. Is it OK? How much performance overhead will be caused by auto scaling hdpi images to fit normal screens?

Thanks.

Comment: Now that xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi have been added, this question is even more relevant now than 5 years ago.  It would be quite difficult to use TraceView to analyze this, as it's done in the background by the android framework itself.  Also it would have to be tested across a variety of phones/tablets and the impact would vary by device.  My personal hunch is that you want at least 2 different resolutions as I'm imagining old devices (2+ years old) being quite slow scaling qHD res images, but it would be great to have the performance data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

If you are filling a listview of 10,000 items with images, then there will be a major performance difference.

If you are running a game engine with even fairly simple graphics, then there will be a major performance difference.

If you are making a custom button background scale, don't worry about it.

As far as simple UI's go, providing multiple resources makes it look better but doesn't really affect performance.

The real performance concern is with sprite scaling in games and other high framerate applications.

Answer (score 1):

None. Do the scaling once at startup and keep the scaled image in memory.

Comment: You're probably better off letting the framework handle the scaling, since it is optimized.

Comment: Err, it could be slow as molasses and it wouldn't matter. It's only going to be done once, that's the whole idea. If the framework does it in 1 second but does it 10,000 times, it will take 10,000 seconds. If doing it yourself takes 5 seconds and you do it once, it will only take 5 seconds. 10,000 > 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate performance statistics using android.os.[Debug](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html) class

Start tracing by executing Debug.startMethodTracing() and stop it with Debug.stopMethodTracing(). File with the trace will be created on sd card.
Then you can analyze it using [TraceView](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) tool.

This should answer you how big is performance overhead of image scaling in your application.

In your position I would generate hdpi set of images and add it to the project.